# Erro MySql inserir

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom, estou tentando criar um menu, e minha sql está retornando o seguinte erro:
Este são os resultado que estão pegando, dei um echo para ver se estava indo corretamente. O Quem somos é o nome que identifica o menu, o 2 é o código de quem é o superior dele e o 0 é a qual publicação ele está vinculado. Para min o erro está no 0, pois não existe nenhum publicação então ele assume o valor 0, porem o 0 é um valor valido para ser um id de menu. Qual a maneira certa para corrigir.

```
Quem Somos20

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jrcomunicacoes`.`tbl_MENU`, CONSTRAINT `FK00` FOREIGN KEY (`COD_PUBLI_VINCU`) REFERENCES `tbl_PUBLICACOES` (`COD_IDENT_PUBLI`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Eu quando estou enviando para o banco eu faço uma validação, onde eu pego o campo e igualo a zero, se for verdadeiro ele retorna null, se for falso eu retorno o valor dele, porem não está dando certo.

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <?php   
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT COD_IDENT_MENUX, TXT_DESCR_MENUX FROM tbl_MENU");
        ?>
          <label>Superior:</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="COD_IDENT_SUPER" name="COD_IDENT_SUPER" >
            <option value="0" selected="selected">Menu Pai</option>
            <?php while($menu = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $menu['COD_IDENT_MENUX'] ?>"><?php echo $menu['TXT_DESCR_MENUX'] ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>
```

A minha query é esta:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_MENU (TXT_DESCR_MENUX, COD_IDENT_SUPER, COD_PUBLI_VINCU) VALUES";
$query .=  "('$titulo','$pai','$publica')";

//executando a query
$inserir = mysql_query($query)
```

Comment: Em que parte do seu código você está fazendo a inserção? Pela mensagem de erro você está querendo alterar um registro que é chave estrangeira em outra tabela.

Comment: Eu mudei para ir null, porem também continua a mesma mensagem @gmsantos

Comment: Renan provavelmente esse campo da sua tabela não suporta nulos. Tem a estrutura do create dela ai ?

Comment: Tenho não como posso obter ? Estou utilizando MySql Workbench

Comment: Clica com o botão direito em cima da tabela `Copy to Clipboard` > `Create Statment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto está ocorrendo porque você está tentando inserir um valor inválido em sua chave estrangeira COD_PUBLI_VINCU. Então

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é tirar o value zero do option:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Menu Pai</option>
```

Se você não quiser tirar o zero você pode tratar na sua aplicação e trocar zero por null.

Depois disso certifique-se que a coluna COD_PUBLI_VINCU aceite o valor NULL.

Answer (score 0):

A resolção par aeste problema é fazer um If, para se caso a pessoa estive inserindo um valor == 0, ele não inclui o valor na query, e se ele inserir um valor maior que zero ou diferente, ele apenas utiliza o valor.

```
if ($publica == 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_MENU (TXT_DESCR_MENUX, COD_IDENT_SUPER) VALUES";
        $query .=  "('$titulo','$pai')";

        //executando a query
        $inserir = mysql_query($query)
        or die(mysql_error());

        $response = array("success" => true);

        //fechando a conexao com o banco
        mysql_close($conn);

        header("Location: cadastroMenu.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante

    }else{

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_MENU (TXT_DESCR_MENUX, COD_IDENT_SUPER, COD_PUBLI_VINCU) VALUES";
    $query .=  "('$titulo','$pai','$publica')";

    //executando a query
    $inserir = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());

    $response = array("success" => true);

    //fechando a conexao com o banco
    mysql_close($conn);

    header("Location: cadastroMenu.php"); exit; // Redireciona o visitante
}
```